# Modify a listbox from other class

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, qlistwidget

I'm making a GUI for a database with pyqt. The database is coding in mysql. Furthermore, the main Window has a QListWidget which allows to see database's data through a update Function.

```
def update(self, bd1='',sql1=''):
try:
    cur = bd1.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql1)
    data = cur.fetchall()
    #print data
    for registro in data:
        #Asignacion de registros a variables
        n = registro[0]
        LName= registro[1]
        Name = registro[2]
        ID = registro[3]
        LName1= registro[4]
        Name1 = registro[5]
        ID1 = registro[6]
        Tip = registro[7]
        Cel = registro[8]
        Tel1 = registro[9]
        Tel2 = registro[10]
        Email= registro[11]
        City = registro[12]

        print 'Entro'
        #Colocacion de datos al listbox
        self.list.addItem(LName + "," + " " + Name)
        self.list.addItem("CC" + " " + ID)

        #Arreglo Cel
        if (Cel==None or LName1==None) or (Tel1==None and Tel2==None) or Email==None:
            pass

        elif Tel1!=None and Tel2==None:
            self.list.addItem("Tel: " + Tel1)
        elif Tel1==None and Tel2!=None:
            print "Error Telefonos en la base de datos"
        else:
            self.list.addItem("Cel: " + Cel)
            self.list.addItem(LName1 + "," + " " + Name1)
            self.list.addItem("CC" + " " + ID1)
            self.list.addItem("Tel: " + Tel1 + " - " + Tel2)
            self.list.addItem("Email: " + Email)

        #Arreglo Ciudad
        if City==None:
            self.list.addItem("Ciudad: " + "Bucaramanga")
        else:
            self.list.addItem("Ciudad: " + City)                    

        #Arreglo Tipologia
        if Tip==None:
            self.list.addItem(" ")
        else:
            self.list.addItem("Tipologia: " + Tip + "\n")


except:
    print "Error en obtencion de datos"
#Desconexion de la BD
bd1.close()
```

Moreover, I created another class that allows to add a new user but when I call the function "update", the list doesn't update with the new data. On the other hand, I have to restart the program for watch the latest updates in the database. What should I do to avoid restart the program and makes update immediately?

Answer (score 0):

If your other function, you need to call `update()` at the end.

```
def add_user():
    # Code to add user to database
    # remember to commit()
    self.list.clear()
    self.update(#appropriate parameters)
```

This clears the `self.list` widget prior to your update call, otherwise you will have duplicate data appearing. When `self.update()` is called, with the appropriate parameters, `self.list` will be repopulated with data from your query.

One thing to remember, after you add a user to the database, be sure to commit your changes. If you don't, your `update()` won't see the new user's information.

Comment: I made that and appeared a mistige                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqt2.py", line 367, in nuser
    self.list.clear()
AttributeError: 'AddWin' object has no attribute 'list'

Comment: Not self.list when called from another class: replace self with whatever you named the instance (mainwindow, maybe?).